# How to implement data integrity while adding data to two database in oracle

Tags: c#, data-integrity

I have a functionality where data from UI needs to be inserted into two database schema in oracle. There are nearly 10 tables where data needs to be added. Is there any way to maintain data integrity(consistency of data in both schema) by either adding all data to both database or delete newly added data from all tables of both database. I have not started coding, just wanted to know whether we have any good approach to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a transaction if you wan't to control the result of all inserts.  There is more than one way to solve this, but you could probably just create an instance of an OracleTransaction object, call a "begin", execute your code then at the end you can commit or rollback.  The other method uses a .net System.Transactions.TransactionScope (which is better) but requires that you install further oracle components.  The latter is useful if you are writing to multiple databases (oracle and SQL Server) and want to maintain integrity.

```
OracleConnection _cn = new OracleConnection();
OracleTransaction _trn = _cn.BeginTransaction();

// command 1
OracleCommand _cmd = new OracleCommand();
_cmd.Transaction = _trn;

// command 2, 3, etc

if (!error) {
  _trn.Commit();
} else {
  _trn.Rollback();
}
```

This is not complete code obviously, just to give you an idea of the structure.